# Python For Loop Print statement

Tags: python, selenium, loops, printing

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


def test_setup():
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(5)


    siteUrls = ["https://www.espncricinfo.com/", "https://www.t20worldcup.com/","https://www.iplt20.com/"]

    for url in siteUrls:
        openSite(url)

def openSite(siteUrl):
    driver.get(siteUrl)
    time.sleep(5)
    print("ESPN website is launched successfully")


def test_teardown():
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

---

Above is my code, it runs perfectly fine, my question is it prints the same statement as output for all 3 URL's, but i want it to print, 3 different statements

for example - I want the below expected output

```
ESPN website is launched successfully
IPL website is launched successfully
world-cup site is launched successfully

But, currently I get output as below ( same statement repeated 3 times)
ESPN website is launched successfully
ESPN website is launched successfully
ESPN website is launched successfully
```

Comment: You don't have any arguments on your print statement .

Comment: How about `print(siteUrl + " is launched successfully")` or  `print(f"{siteUrl} is launched successfully")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide an appropriate name as a second argument to `openSite`. For example,

```
    ...

    siteUrls = [
        ("ESPN", "https://www.espncricinfo.com/"),
        ("world-cup", "https://www.t20worldcup.com/"),
        ("IPL", "https://www.iplt20.com/")
    ]

    for name, url in siteUrls:
        openSite(name, url)


def openSite(name, siteUrl):
    driver.get(siteUrl)
    time.sleep(5)
    print(f"{name} website is launched successfully")
```

Comment: Did you redefine `siteUrls` as shown in the answer?

Comment: Hey chepner - I am extremely sorry, yes your code works fine too...my fault, missed something when i executed

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any arguments on your print statement. That's why you always get the same output. Here is a possible solution:

```
def openSite(siteUrl):
    driver.get(siteUrl)
    time.sleep(5)
    print(siteUrl, "is launched successfully")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def openSite(siteUrl):
    driver.get(siteUrl)
    time.sleep(5)

    # Split the url at the period and get index 1 from list that contains site name
    site_name = siteUrl.split('.')[1]
    print(site_name + " website is launched successfully")

#output:
#>> espncricinfo website is launched successfully
#>> t20worldcup website is launched successfully
#>> iplt20website is launched successfully
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass something to your print statement. For example

```
print(f"{siteUrl} launched")
```